# While update index object value have double quotes throws exception

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to update index using update script, if index object value have double quotes I am getting exception.

Using the following code:

```
Employee employee = Employee();
employee.setId(16661L);
employee.setEmployeeId(11026L);
employee.setEmployeeName("Ashok"s Kumar");
employee.setEmailId("ashokkumar@yahoo.com");

final StringBuilder updateScript = new StringBuilder("ctx._source.employees.add("
                + employee + ");");

final UpdateRequestBuilder request = CLIENT.prepareUpdate(indexName, String.valueOf("88"), "14344");
final UpdateResponse response = request.setScript(updateScript.toString()).execute().actionGet();
```

while execute this getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException: failed to execute script
    at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:187)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:183)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:63)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.instance.TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction$AsyncSingleAction$1.run(TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction.java:191)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: [Error: unterminated string literal]
[Near : {... umar","emailId":"ashokkumar@yahoo.com"}); ....}]
                                                                                           ^
[Line: 1, Column: 250]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.mvel2.util.ParseTools.balancedCapture(ParseTools.java:1395)
```

Any one have solution for this please?

Answer (score 0):

Please try by replacing

```
employeeName = employeeName.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Comment: I already tried with this replace it wont work. In my code Employee object employee Name field have double quotes. if we replace also update script will be in this format
ctx._source.projectPeople.add({
    "id": 16661,
    "employeeId": 11026,
    "employeeName": "Ashok\\"s Kumar ",
    "emailId ":"akil@berijam.com"
    });
so employeeName get "Ashok\\" only so getting exception.